# Automatically ellipsize a string in Java

Tags: java, string

Is there a method in Java to automatically ellipsize a string? Just in Java, not other libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Nvm... Btw how can I remove comments?...

Comment: `Just in Java, not other libraries.` Sorry, I should start to read the questions :( Although it is good practice to reuse existing libraries like `StringUtils`. It's what they are here for... And it might save you some work. http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: @moxn thanks for the link, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately I have to be careful with importing new external JARs, also for license problems (project I work on is closed source). This one seems to be Apache 2.0 so it shouldn't be a problem., right?

Comment: `StringUtils` link above no longer active. Active link as of today: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on your use case, it might be useful to put the ellipsis between letters (i.e. add letters at the end to provide some context):

```
/**
 * Puts ellipses in input strings that are longer than than maxCharacters. Shorter strings or
 * null is returned unchanged.
 * @param input the input string that may be subjected to shortening
 * @param maxCharacters the maximum characters that are acceptable for the unshortended string. Must be at least 3, otherwise a string with ellipses is too long already.
 * @param charactersAfterEllipsis the number of characters that should appear after the ellipsis (0 or larger) 
 * @return the truncated string with trailing ellipses
 */
public static String ellipsize(String input, int maxCharacters, int charactersAfterEllipsis) {
  if(maxCharacters < 3) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxCharacters must be at least 3 because the ellipsis already take up 3 characters");
  }
  if(maxCharacters - 3 > charactersAfterEllipsis) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("charactersAfterEllipsis must be less than maxCharacters");
  }
  if (input == null || input.length() < maxCharacters) {
    return input;
  }
  return input.substring(0, maxCharacters - 3 - charactersAfterEllipsis) + "..." + input.substring(input.length() - charactersAfterEllipsis);
}
```

There are also more sophisticated features you might want from you ellipsis algorithm: If you need to place the text into a graphical element and you are using a proportional font, then you must measure the length of the String.

For Swing/AWT that would be `java.awt.Font.getStringBounds`. In such a case, a simple algrithm would cut the string one letter at a time and add the ellipsis, until the string fits into the limit given. If used often, the bisection method elaborated in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoEllipsis.aspx?msg=3278640 (C#, but should be easy enough to translate to Java) may save some processor cycles.

Comment: I have implemented something along the lines of what you suggested. Thanks!
I think I'll try to provide a general String-ellipsising class, for now I needed a quick hack inside a class, but it's worth trying to invest some time and develop a good API.

Comment: I think you should use the ellipsis char, …, not three dots, that may be divided in the end of a line (appart from being only 1 length instead of 3)

Comment: @Wakka you are right, if the ellipsis is available on the output, then it may be a good choice (e.g. when using Swing). For certain applications three dots should be acceptable as well: If the target does not support the ellipsis character (e.g. if the output uses ISO-8859-1) or for fixed-width fonts where ellipsis only takes one width instead of 3.

Comment: @nd.yeah, that's true. f*** encoding ;-)

Comment: if(maxCharacters - 3 > charactersAfterEllipsis) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("charactersAfterEllipsis must be less than maxCharacters");
  } you should invert with (!(...))

Answer (score 9):

This method will return the ellipsized String:

```
String ellipsize(String input, int maxLength) {
    String ellip = "...";
    if (input == null || input.length() <= maxLength 
           || input.length() < ellip.length()) {
        return input;
    }
    return input.substring(0, maxLength - ellip.length()).concat(ellip);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is not. But here's another crack at a simple method to do this.

```
String ellipsize(String input, int maxLength) {
  if (input == null || input.length() < maxLength) {
    return input;
  }
  return input.substring(0, maxLength) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A oneliner which of course does not outperform the other offered solutions:

```
longString.replaceFirst("(.{5}).+(.{5})", "$1...$2")
```

Will leave only first and last 5 characters and put ... in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, try this one:

```
public static String ellipsise (String input, int maxLen) {
    if (input == null)
        return null;
    if ((input.length() < maxLen) || (maxLen < 3))
        return input;
    return input.substring (0, maxLen - 3) + "...";
}
```

This has the advantage of fixing the bug where the King's English is not used properly :-)

Comment: The King's English - sorry?!

Comment: @Buffalo, you're stretching my memory a bit, this answer was posted six years ago. However, I suspect I meant that the King's English (rather than the quaint US variant) uses `ise` (not `ize`) at the ends of words like `ellipsise`. That'd be my best guess given the playful smiley and the fact I've spelt it differently.