# Short string format

Tags: java

I've an array with hundreds of string values, Is it possible to use specific formats to make them shorter?

> e.g
>
> Normal -> "Hello John, What's up?!"
>
> With short format -> "Hello John..."

After using substring, I got errors.

```
private String[] finalString;
for (int i = 0; i < arrays.PodcastTitle.length; i++) {
    finalString[i] = arrays.PodcastTitle[i].substring(0, 5); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specific formats"?

Comment: Do the array contains all similar kind of strings?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? How are you describing the short formats?

Comment: Do you mean keeping the first 2 words, followed by ...? or first x characters followed by ...? Something else?

Comment: Do you mean `String.format`? => I don't think so. But what you want can be easily done using length() and substring().

Comment: You "got errors" - what errors? One error I see in the code above is that you don't initialize `finalString`, so it will be `null`, leading to a `NullPointerException` when you try to assign to `finalString[i]`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288716/automatically-ellipsize-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't given any details, this is the shortest approach :

```
String little = normalString.substring(0, 10); // use anything 5 or 10 or 15, depending on how short you want to make your String
```

From your edit:

Please change:

```
private String[] finalString;
```

to:

```
private String[] finalString = new String[whateverSizeYouWant];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String toLitteString(String str, int length) {
     if (str.length() > length) return str.substring(0, length) + "...";
     return str;
}
```

Function that will truncate longer strings to length (and add a "...") or return the short string. If you want the length to include the "..." then just change `length` to `length - 3`.

Comment: Use `str.substring(0, length - 3)` so the length still holds when "..." has been appended.

Comment: Thanks, guess it depends on how he wants it. Added!

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you consider implementing a method that takes a String argument, explodes it by space character and returns the String with required number of words in it?