# Android TextView in one line

Tags: android, textview

There is my code below. I need obtain result like on this snipset:

When is short string:

```
1 line:  ABC (123)
```

When is long string:

```
1 line:  ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC...(123)
```

Any help?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I need keep in one line long and short string. but current the second parametr is not visible, it is overlay buy first one

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247018/android-textview-singleline-field-hides-long-text

Answer (score 2):

You can also use RelativeLayout and property like below..

1. alignParentRight for second TextView.
2. First TextView toLeftOf of Second TextView.

Here is sample code.. Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/id2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="123"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output is like below images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this property android:singleLine="true" in your Textview

Comment: Ok, but te second parametr is not visible

Comment: Can you give the detail info about your second parameter? How you want to show?

Comment: I need Align to left for short string ABC (parametr: id2)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the String length, if its longer than a specific length, than you can display it like you want.

ex. max length you want is 20

```
if (str.length()>20) {
    str = str.substring(0, 20)+"..."; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, but te second parametr is not visible

Comment: Concate the second parameter in your string `str = str.substring(0, 20)+"..."+secondParameterStr;`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="123"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_form"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, but te second parametr is not visible

Comment: Double check please. It works. Note these code : android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: It is ok, How to align to left, for better user experience?

Comment: the second one android:id="@+id/id2"

Comment: Do you know when the string is short and when it is long? If yes, I will update my answer.

Comment: No, I need something floating

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
    String s = "ABC ABC ABC ABC";

        if(s.split(" ").length>1)
        {
            s = s.split(" ")[0]+" ("+s.split(" ").length+")";
        }

textView.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your xml

```
android:ellipsize="middle"
android:singleLine="true"
```