# When I display a whitespace followed by long string in android textview, it skips the first line and displays the actual string on the next

Tags: android, string, textview

I am having trouble while displaying a string in textview

```
policyValTv.setText(": " +trimPolicyNo);
```

Problem is if the trimPolicyNo is a long string, then the textview(policyValTv) displays the whitespace but breaks the line and displays the actual string on the next line. How can I avoid this? I want to display all on one line but not keep singleLine = true. Please help

Comment: [read this][1] maybe can help you ...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25247093/1651200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `policyValTv.setText(":\u00A0" +trimPolicyNo);` where \u00A0 is the unicode char for non breaking space.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your textView in layout `XML`

```
 android:maxLines="2"
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:singleLine="false"
```