# How to change Text Size for differrent screen size?

Tags: android, text, size

I am making Game with android studio everything is completed but only one issue i have. Text size's not changed. How to make it for auto fit on any screen like phones and tablets.

Comment: are you using `android:textSize`  with sp (scalled pixels) in your layout?

Comment: s but not working for all screens

Comment: can you please show some code of how you set the text size?

Comment: Please provide more Information. Are you using a TextView or do you draw with canvas or anything else?

Comment: write different size in dimensions for different screen size.

Comment: @sabish did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Demo Git Project [Android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).It may help you.In your layout add like this to mention size  `android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"`.

Comment: i need single word text to fit in layout on any screen

Comment: Its not possible .How can you set very long text in single line .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247018/android-textview-singleline-field-hides-long-text

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)
to auto fit your text depend on `TextView` width.
also you need to set `android:textSize` in `dimens.xml` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"/>
```

for have different size for different devices just define `dimens.xml` for different screen size (for example: Value-large)

Comment: i need single word text to fit in layout on any screen